# Disable Compatibility View Through Code In IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, standards

I for some reason am calling a doctype preferably XHTML 1.0 Transitional, and for some reason every single time I open it in Internet Explorer I get...

Browser Mode: IE9 Compat View
Document Mode: IE7 Standards

I'll even include what my doctype looks like with the beginning of my head tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
```

And yes, I do close `<body>` and `<html>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the markup itself actually conforms using a validator?

Comment: Take a look at this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#Backward_compatibility).  I think this is the correct way to do it.  Does your `html` element look like the first example's?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, good idea.  This is [the W3C's validator](http://validator.w3.org/).  That doesn't mean MS will conform to it though.  Paste your whole page in the direct input, or give it a link.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Yes, I have, via W3C.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's the documentation you are looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Include this and IE will render as in IE9 mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Comment: better yet is IE=Edge, this will make sure it renders in the most standards compliant mode in future versions.

Comment: @Sologoub: Awesome, this is what I want to do, but how do I know that if the Web-Page is viewed in Internet Explorer 7 it will view it in Internet Explorer 7 standards? Same with Internet Explorer 8? And even later versions of Internet Explorer? Thanks! :)

Comment: @AaronBrewer - if you use the IE=Edge I mentioned, that will be the case.

Comment: I suggest that @Sologoub edits the answer including the edge option and closing the meta tag with />

Comment: meta tags should only be closed if you're using xhtml, in html they should be unclosed (although html5 allows both).

Comment: I'm using IE11 and facing this issue - the meta tag for 'IE=Edge' is still not fixing this problem. Hoping I can find a solution without requiring every user of the app to go in and change this setting.

Answer (score 10):

By default, IE will render in compatibility mode for websites on the same subnet as the client.  You can fix this by either turning off this feature in IE by going to Tools->Compatibility View Settings and unchecking Display Intranet sites in compatibility mode, or by including the meta tag that Sologoub mentioned.

Comment: @AaronBrewer - apparently you didn't read the last part of my message, which suggested using the meta tag.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't comprehend your answer well enough. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Just came across this answer trying to solve the same thing.  Any idea *why* IE behaviour defaults this way?  We have 100s of PCs that have been recently upgraded to Windows 7, and I can foresee some issues.

Comment: @Moo-Juice - this was not introduced in Windows 7.  It was introduced in Vista, with IE7.  The reason is that, at the time, most corporate customers needed their sites to default to compatibility view to work correctly.  There is also a group policy setting that can control this.  See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8ffc9e6c-dfdb-428b-92aa-cd3ddb304d6c/internet-explorer-9-compatability-view-gpo?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Answer (score 10):

I have this issure too. And I found a solution :

insert meta tag in header HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

and  set the equivalant header:

header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge');

Or if you use Zend Framework (or any framework for that matter), something like this will do
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getResponse()->setHeader('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=Edge');

solution in this link :

http://www.enrise.com/2012/03/internet-explorer-9-compatibility-view-list/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need to be a bit more comprehensive so that you target all the possible user overrides.  Certainly for single-page apps like Meteor:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE; Chrome=1" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice knowing who you specify multiple versions.