# Stuck with IE compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers, x-ua-compatible, compatibility-mode

The URL of the site I am working on ended up on Microsoft compatibility list. This means that every time IE users visit it, IE9 mode is forced on which makes it impossible to use modern CSS or Javascript.

[image]

First 6 lines of every HTML document on the site look like these. There are no conditional comments. I also tried to put `<title>` title immediately after the `<head>` without any success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>...</title>
```

Response HTTP headers always contain

```
X-UA-Compatible     IE=Edge
```

But it does not appear to make any difference. The only thing that forces IE off IE9 mode is this checkbox in the Setting dialog. Only when it is unset, the site is displayed in the Edge mode.

[image]

Plus, I recently found that Microsoft's iecompatdata.xml contains `featureSwitch="overrideXUACompatible:false"` attribute next to the site entry.

Is there anything else I can try to prevent my site from being displayed in IE compatibility mode?

Comment: How are you currently implementing the X-UA-Compatible response header? PHP|htaccess? The other option I can think of, is to use the browser version instead of 'edge', on the server side. That's what I do anyway.

Comment: Use this: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />



Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650557/disable-compatibility-view-through-code-in-ie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the site is on Microsoft's compatibility view list, you'll need to get them to remove it.

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622935.aspx), you need to email **iepo@microsoft.com** with the following information and ask that your site be removed from the list:

- Owner Name
- Corporate Title
- Email Address
- Telephone Number
- Company Name
- Street Address
- Website Address

Answer (score 1):

Send it as a header instead.  By the time the meta tag is interpreted, the decision may already have been made; this will not be the case with the header.

More detail and instructions at [this other SO post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13287226/763127).

Comment: Oh.  I'm sorry; I was really hoping that'd do it for you.

Comment: I suspect that overrideXUACompatible attribute in compatibility list XML file might have something to do with it

Answer (score 0):

You may have already seen this...
[Force IE compatibility mode off using tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-in-ie-using-tags)

This response in particular may be of interest...

"I have found that this does NOT work if the user (or the sysadmin) has turned on compatibility mode as a default by going to Tools->Compatibility View Settings, and checking Display all websites in Compatibility View. To fix the problem, I have to return the header in the HTTP response: X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge" –  speedplane Apr 19 '13 at 11:29

Also...
"Word of advice for those who find this answer, but are unable to get it to work for them. The compatability meta tag MUST be the first meta tag, and there can be NO IE conditional statements before the tag." More: tesmond.blogspot.com/2011/10/… –  Chris Sobolewski

Is your meta the first one on the page?

Comment: There is no such checkbox in IE. At least not in IE11

Comment: Do you have any other meta tags before it or IE conditionals?

Comment: There aren't any: <html><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">